# What would this sauce be called?

Tags: sauce

I have a nice sized chuck roast in the sous-vide circulator, I can see that there are some great looking juices accumulating in the bag. I want to make a sauce out of those juices with butter, garlic, herbs and wine reduction. There is a name for that kind of sauce, but it's escaping me at the moment. So that I can Google for recipes, what would a sauce like that be called?

Answer (score 8):

Using the meat juices from cooking is a `jus` :) adding wine along with the aromatics might change it to be a "red wine jus" or I've also seen a "port jus", or the `jus` could be used in a Madeira sauce, etc.

> served in the natural juices that flow from the meat as it cooks.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/au%20jus

Comment: And remember that "au jus", linked, means literally "with juice", referring to something served in the sauce, so don't say "with au jus" or "with au jus sauce" as I have seen sometimes.

Comment: Never seen that, lol ouch :) Like ATM machine & PIN number!

Answer (score 5):

The other answers here are probably technically more correct, but I did find the word that I was looking for. That word is [*Bordelaise*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bordelaise_sauce).

Comment: Could also be called a reduction.

Answer (score 2):

I've often heard these kinds of things called pan sauces. I think it originally refers to drippings (and maybe fond) from the cooking pan, but the idea is still meat stuff + other stuff + cooking/reducing, so it's not surprising people apply the name to sous vide juices as well.

Answer (score 1):

Could be as simple as [`gravy`](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=gravey&oq=gravey&aqs=chrome..69i57.1991j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=gravey%20definition).

> **gravy**
>   ˈɡreɪvi/ noun
>
> 1. a sauce made by mixing the fat and juices exuded by meat during cooking with stock and other ingredients.

Comment: Gravy typically contains flour or some other sort of starch or thickening agent, which the question doesn't mention.